# What does ${##} mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I know `$#` is the number of positional parameters in `bash`. But how does `bash` interpret `${##}`? Here, is a sample output from my system.

```
$ echo $#
0
$ echo ${#}
0
$ echo ${##}
1
$ echo $##
0#
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$#` is the number of positional parameters, and `${##}` is the length of `$#`'s value in characters; in other words it's the base 10 logarithm plus one, rounded down, of the number of positional parameters. `$##` doesn't work because it doesn't comply with the parameter expansion syntax.

Observe:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "$# ${##}"' _ {1..9}
9 1
$ bash -c 'echo "$# ${##}"' _ {1..10}
10 2
$ bash -c 'echo "$# ${##}"' _ {1..100}
100 3
```

See [Bash Reference Manual § 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for further information.